# Does setInterval() re-evaluates the content of the function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout

I am writing an amateur SPA, based on Vue (specifically the Quasar framework).

This application, in `mounted()`, connects to an MQTT broker to get some information (MQTT does not matter here - it could be an API called with `fetch()`, the point is that the results are available "after some time" in JS asynchronous way). This information is stored in `this.results`.

I use `this.results` in some components and the content is displayed as expected, and updated upon new results (i.e. a change in `this.results`) as expected as well.

Since this a front end for a home monitring program, I wanted to also display the last time the results were fetched and raise alerts if I did not get new results for some time (that would suggest that the monitoring backend itself crashed). I went for:

```
mounted() {
    // connect to the MQTT broker = new results will come. That could be a setInterval fetch()
    this.client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://mqtt.swtk.info:1884");
    this.client.on("connect", this.mqttConnect);
    this.client.on("message", this.mqttMessage);
    // check every 900 ms for the last time I got the results, and set a variable for the elapsed time
    setInterval(
      function() {
        console.log(this.results)
        this.timeSinceLastRun = moment().unix() - moment(this.results.when).unix()
      },
      900
    )
  }
```

This is the message I continuously (every second) get on the console:

[image]

At the same time, `this.results` **is** defined: not only cntents from `this.results` are otherwise correctly displayed in components, but when looking at the DevTool Vue tab, I
I see:

[image]

It looks like the `this.result` in the `setInterval()` function is assessed only once and is `undefined` - which is fine because it would not have been received at that time yet, but will shortly be set (upon getting the first results).

**Shouldn't its value be used as it is "currently" in each of the 900 ms calls to the function?**

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` instead and you will see the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use arrow function `() => {}` like this

```
setInterval(
      () => {
        console.log(this.results)
        this.timeSinceLastRun = moment().unix() - moment(this.results.when).unix()
      },
      900
    )
```